# Screen turns gray on boot after install of a PPA

Tags: 10.10, kernel, apt, ppa, add-apt-repository

**Problem**
I recently added [ppa:eugenesan/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eeugenesan/+archive/ppa) to my maverick installation to install [smartgit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). Right after apt-get listed a bunch of updates that I immediately installed. After rebooting I noticed that grub changed. The new version of grub is `1.99~rc1-2ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1`. Booting up my system I had to admit that it no longer launches the login screen. It still shows the Ubuntu logo (new style also) but after that the **screen turns gray**.

**Solution ideas**
I already found the apt-get history under `/var/log/apt/history.log` and it lists all the software that came with the new repository. The list is huge.

Further, I read that `ppa-purge` can [uninstall a repository and all its software](http://disfunctions.de/tutorials/ppa-purge/). I am not sure if I understood right since it does not affect the grub version installed. That would be the easiest to see.

Can you help me to fix my system? I have access to the command line.

---

**Vague solution steps**
Thanks to [Lekensteyn](https://askubuntu.com/users/6969/lekensteyn). In the meantime I read and tried what was written in the other thread. Nonetheless, I cannot uninstall the software version that came by `eugenesan`. This is what I tried:

```bash
sudo ppa-purge ppa:eugenesan/ppa
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eugenesan...
```

Moreover, I found out that a "Previous Linux version" boots up normally. The default grub entries are `Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-31-generic` and `..(recovery mode)` - the couple that does not boot up.
But when I choose `Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.35-30-generic` from the list, everything works **fine**. Do you understand what happens? Could it be that the graphic resolution is just set wrong OR do you think grub is the problem?

**Installation log**
To give a complete overview I got the `history.log` for apt-get. This is what happened in the meantime.

```bash
# ***** /var/log/apt/history.log *****

Start-Date: 2011-12-07  19:33:18
Commandline: apt-get install smartgit
Install: smartgit:amd64 (2.1.4-0~eugenesan~maverick9)
End-Date: 2011-12-07  19:33:36

Start-Date: 2011-12-07  19:50:00
Install:
libfile-desktopentry-perl:amd64 (0.04-2),
isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.1.1-P1-15ubuntu3.2~eugenesan~maverick1),
ttf-fixedsys-excelsior:amd64 (3.0-1ubuntu2~eugenesan~maverick2),
libfile-mimeinfo-perl:amd64 (0.15-1),
isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.1.1-P1-15ubuntu3.2~eugenesan~maverick1, automatic),
p7zip-full:amd64 (9.04~dfsg.1-1)


Upgrade:
meld:amd64 (1.3.2-1ubuntu1, 1.5.0-0ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1),
codeblocks:amd64 (10.05-0ubuntu1, 10.05-1~eugenesan~maverick1),
git-all:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
libglib2.0-data:amd64 (2.26.1-0ubuntu1, 2.28.0-0ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1),
git-daemon-run:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
network-manager-gnome:amd64 (0.8.1+git.20100809t190028.290dc70-0ubuntu3, 0.8.3+git.20110203t003354.9bf0b98-0ubuntu1~nmt1~maverick),
git-doc:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
git-cvs:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
git-gui:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
rubygems:amd64 (1.3.7-2, 1.5.3-0~eugenesan~maverick2),
libnm-util1:amd64 (0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2, 0.8.3+git.20110201t160144.9b61ec7-0ubuntu1~nmt2~maverick),
git-man:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
screen:amd64 (4.0.3-14ubuntu4, 4.1.0git066b098-0~eugenesan~maverick3),
libpcre3:amd64 (8.02-1, 8.12-1~eugenesan~maverick1),
hotot:amd64 (0.9.7~git-1259-g63e05cf-0ubuntu0ppa1~maverick1, 0.9.7~git-1280-g9b00609-0ubuntu0ppa1~maverick1),
git-svn:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
libsoup-gnome2.4-1:amd64 (2.31.92-0ubuntu1.1, 2.32.2-2ub~eugenesan~maverick1),
grub-pc:amd64 (1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3.3, 1.99~rc1-2ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1),
libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.26.1-0ubuntu1, 2.28.0-0ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1),
git-email:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
network-manager:amd64 (0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2, 0.8.3+git.20110201t160144.9b61ec7-0ubuntu1~nmt2~maverick),
gitweb:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
git:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
libnm-glib2:amd64 (0.8.1+git.20100810t184654.ab580f4-0ubuntu2, 0.8.3+git.20110201t160144.9b61ec7-0ubuntu1~nmt2~maverick),
codeblocks-common:amd64 (10.05-0ubuntu1, 10.05-1~eugenesan~maverick1),
rdesktop:amd64 (1.6.0-3ubuntu2.1, 1.7.0-1ubuntu2~eugenesan~maverick1),
libglib2.0-bin:amd64 (2.26.1-0ubuntu1, 2.28.0-0ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1),
git-el:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
libglib2.0-dev:amd64 (2.26.1-0ubuntu1, 2.28.0-0ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1),
xdg-utils:amd64 (1.0.2+cvs20100307-1ubuntu0.3, 1.1.0~rc1-2~eugenesan~maverick1),
initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.98.1ubuntu6.1, 0.99ubuntu2.1~eugenesan~maverick1),
y-ppa-manager:amd64 (0.0.8.4-1~webupd8~maverick3, 0.0.8.5-1~webupd8~maverick),
codeblocks-contrib:amd64 (10.05-0ubuntu1, 10.05-1~eugenesan~maverick1),
git-arch:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
gitk:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
dhcp3-client:amd64 (3.1.3-2ubuntu6.3, 4.1.1-P1-15ubuntu3.2~eugenesan~maverick1),
libcodeblocks0:amd64 (10.05-0ubuntu1, 10.05-1~eugenesan~maverick1),
rubygems1.8:amd64 (1.3.7-2, 1.5.3-0~eugenesan~maverick2),
python-support:amd64 (1.0.9ubuntu1, 1.0.10ubuntu3~eugenesan~maverick1),
git-core:amd64 (1.7.7.2-1~ppa0~maverick1, 1.7.8-0ppa1~maverick1),
ttf-mscorefonts-installer:amd64 (3.2ubuntu2, 3.3ubuntu4~eugenesan~maverick4),
shutter:amd64 (0.88~ppa4~maverick1, 0.88.1~ppa3~maverick1),
handbrake-gtk:amd64 (4370svnppa1~maverick1, 4373svnppa1~maverick1),
python-gdata:amd64 (2.0.8-1.1, 2.0.13-1~eugenesan~maverick1),
grub-common:amd64 (1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3.3, 1.99~rc1-2ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1),
libjson-glib-1.0-0:amd64 (0.10.2-2ubuntu2.1, 0.12.2-0ubuntu1~eugenesan~maverick1),
libwxsmithlib0:amd64 (10.05-0ubuntu1, 10.05-1~eugenesan~maverick1),
ppa-purge:amd64 (0.2.8+bzr56~webupd8~maverick, 0.2.8+bzr59-0~61~maverick1),
initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 (0.98.1ubuntu6.1, 0.99ubuntu2.1~eugenesan~maverick1),
dhcp3-common:amd64 (3.1.3-2ubuntu6.3, 4.1.1-P1-15ubuntu3.2~eugenesan~maverick1),
libsoup2.4-1:amd64 (2.31.92-0ubuntu1.1, 2.32.2-2ub~eugenesan~maverick1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)    
End-Date: 2011-12-07  20:03:24

Start-Date: 2011-12-08  11:31:33
Commandline: apt-get remove
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2011-12-08  11:31:35

Start-Date: 2011-12-08  11:37:57
Commandline: apt-get install ppa-purge
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2011-12-08  11:37:58

Start-Date: 2011-12-08  11:38:59
Commandline: apt-get remove rubygems1.8
Remove: 
rubygems:amd64 (1.5.3-0~eugenesan~maverick2), 
rubygems1.8:amd64 (1.5.3-0~eugenesan~maverick2)
End-Date: 2011-12-08  11:39:08

Start-Date: 2011-12-08  12:01:08
Commandline: apt-get purge screen
Purge: 
ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.207), 
byobu:amd64 (3.5-0ubuntu1.1), 
ubuntu-netbook:amd64 (2.035), 
screen:amd64 (4.1.0git066b098-0~eugenesan~maverick3)
End-Date: 2011-12-08  12:01:20
```

All entries from `Start-Date: 2011-12-08  11:31:33` and later are already me trying to fix the system. There seems to be an **error** in the initial "eugenesan-installation"

---

**Kernel under suspicion**
Could it be that `kernel 2.6.35-31` is not working on my machine? I cannot see an installation had happened in the `history.log`, though. In case I want to remove the kernel I found an article on [how to remove a grub menu entry](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17787/clean-up-the-new-ubuntu-grub2-boot-menu/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: unfortunate title which would have meant this is a dup - however give the latest info - probably a genuine problem.  I've changed the title to reflect the actual question asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `kernel 2.6.35-31` [as already mentioned](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17787/clean-up-the-new-ubuntu-grub2-boot-menu/). I am totally unsure about what happened. But in the meantime I can use my system again.