# Ubuntu 18.04.4 startup stuck after package updates / mesa segmentation fault

Tags: boot, 18.04, xorg, mesa, segmentation-fault

## TL;DR

> /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x56131d0000f7

## The startup problem

I shut down Ubuntu 18.04.4 on my machine today and cold-started it somewhat later. Now it starts but **no longer reaches the UI stage**. The start process ends with the following output on the screen (tail of the output):

```
...
[  OK  ] Started Hostname Service.
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager.
         Starting Network Manager Wait Online...
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting OpenVPN service...
[  OK  ] Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
[  OK  ] Started OpenVPN service.
         Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting hold until boot process finishes up...
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Started Disk Manager.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
```

**Note:** When I start again the order of shell outputs differs.

The only thing I can do is to press the `POWER` button. As a result Ubuntu shuts down.

## GRUB & recovery mode

I entered into GRUB (2.02) by pressing the right `SHIFT` key at boot time.

I am using Linux `4.15.0.-112-generic`. There are also `4.15.0.-111-generic`, `4.2.0.-42-generic`, `4.2.0.-41-generic`, `3.13.0.-64-generic`, ... available.

When I select `4.15.0.-112-generic (recovery mode)` then the boot process does not get further. But I get to the `Recovery menu: filesystem state: read-only)`.

[image: Recovery menu]

When I choose `Resume normal boot` I get to the usual UI login.

## apt history

I looked into `/var/log/apt/history.log` and found these:

```sh
Start-Date: 2020-08-03  19:33:21
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.368'
Upgrade: 
libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.45+dfsg-1ubuntu1.5, 2.4.45+dfsg-1ubuntu1.6), 
slack-desktop:amd64 (4.7.0, 4.8.0), 
python3-distupgrade:amd64 (1:18.04.37, 1:18.04.38), 
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:amd64 (1:18.04.37, 1:18.04.38), 
libldap-common:amd64 (2.4.45+dfsg-1ubuntu1.5, 2.4.45+dfsg-1ubuntu1.6), 
code:amd64 (1.47.0-1594283939, 1.47.3-1595520028), 
ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:amd64 (1:18.04.37, 1:18.04.38), 
mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-08-03  19:33:43

Start-Date: 2020-08-03  19:37:12
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.368'
Upgrade: 
git-gui:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-man:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-svn:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-daemon-sysvinit:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1),
gitk:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
gitweb:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-mediawiki:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-email:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-all:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-cvs:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-doc:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1), 
git-el:amd64 (1:2.27.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu18.04.1, 1:2.28.0-0ppa1~ubuntu18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-08-03  19:37:31

Start-Date: 2020-08-03  19:38:54
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.368'
Upgrade: 
libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
mesa-common-dev:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
cifs-utils:amd64 (2:6.8-1, 2:6.8-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2020-08-03  19:39:00

Start-Date: 2020-08-03  19:40:55
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.368'
Upgrade: brave-browser:amd64 (1.10.97, 1.11.104)
End-Date: 2020-08-03  19:41:10

Start-Date: 2020-08-03  19:42:16
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.368'
Upgrade: 
libglapi-mesa:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libglx-mesa0:amd64 (19.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.3, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1)
End-Date: 2020-08-03  19:42:19

Start-Date: 2020-08-03  19:43:14
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.368'
Upgrade: 
grub-common:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.15, 2.02-2ubuntu8.17), 
grub2-common:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.15, 2.02-2ubuntu8.17), 
grub-pc:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.15, 2.02-2ubuntu8.17), 
grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.15, 2.02-2ubuntu8.17)
End-Date: 2020-08-03  19:43:29
```

## System log

I looked into the `syslog` and found a **segmentation fault** there which looks suspicious:

```
...
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP systemd[5094]: Reached target Basic System.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 125.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP systemd[5094]: Reached target Default.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP systemd[5094]: Startup finished in 54ms.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (--) Log file renamed from "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.pid-5108.log" to "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Release Date: 2017-12-20
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Current Operating System: Linux COMP 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-112-generic root=UUID=e15b2ef7-c32d-46f5-a3a8-4bdc60285b4e ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Build Date: 03 June 2019  08:10:35AM
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011to make sure that you have the latest version.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Log file: "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Aug  4 18:07:47 2020
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Using a default monitor configuration.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Automatically adding devices
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Automatically enabling devices
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Entry deleted from font path.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) FontPath set to:
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011built-ins
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loader magic: 0x56131c3ef020
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Module ABI versions:
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (++) using VT number 1
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c94
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:2a42:17aa:2112 rev 7, Mem @ 0xf4400000/4194304, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00001800/8, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (--) PCI: (0:0:2:1) 8086:2a43:17aa:2112 rev 7, Mem @ 0xf4200000/1048576
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) LoadModule: "glx"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011Module class: X.Org Video Driver
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011"Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (II) glamor: OpenGL accelerated X.org driver based.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) Backtrace:
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x56131c15fabd]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x56131bfa7000+0x1bc859) [0x56131c163859]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7fdd821dc000+0x128a0) [0x7fdd821ee8a0]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7fdd7945c000+0x129cc) [0x7fdd7946e9cc]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 4: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7fdd7945c000+0x1b19e) [0x7fdd7947719e]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7fdd7945c000+0x216df) [0x7fdd7947d6df]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7fdd7945c000+0x1ac0b) [0x7fdd79476c0b]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 7: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7fdd7945c000+0x16b7d) [0x7fdd79472b7d]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7fdd7945c000+0x16bc5) [0x7fdd79472bc5]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 9: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL_mesa.so.0 (0x7fdd7945c000+0x10948) [0x7fdd7946c948]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so (glamor_egl_init+0x10b) [0x7fdd7ea75c9b]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so (0x7fdd7f2b3000+0x9dc9) [0x7fdd7f2bcdc9]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 12: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0xc08) [0x56131c040288]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x56131bfa7000+0x56cd3) [0x56131bffdcd3]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 14: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7fdd81e0cb97]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) 15: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x56131bfe7b8a]
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x56131d0000f7
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Fatal server error:
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: #011 at http://wiki.x.org
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]:  for help.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE)
Aug  4 18:07:47 COMP /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5106]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file
...
```

## Bug filed

- See: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/3372

## Next steps suggested

I suspect that the startup problem is caused by recent package updates. I might have installed a **partial package** accidentally as I remember there was a warning about this in the `Software Updater` window. What would be the best to get the system back into a stable state?

## Related

- [Screen turns gray on boot after install of a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86118/screen-turns-gray-on-boot-after-install-of-a-ppa)
- [The Mesa 3D Graphics Library](https://mesa3d.org)

---

## A step by step solution

1. Since there is a segmentation fault happening with "mesa" I removed all packages via `sudo apt-get remove mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 mesa-va-drivers:amd64 libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 mesa-common-dev:amd64 libglapi-mesa:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libglx-mesa0:amd64` which occur in the *history.log* listed above. As a result Ubuntu starts into a shell prompt.
2. Then I tried to install some up-to-date "mesa" packages. I found [ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa) and added it via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa && sudo apt-get update`.
3. Then I installed via `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils libglu1-mesa-dev xserver-xorg-video-all` without knowing what is needed.

<strike>Still UI is not starting.</strike>

4. Then I took a look at `/var/log/dpkg.log` and saw among others that `gdm3:amd64` (GNOME display manager) was removed. I installed it, restarted and luckily could login again.

<strike>But the desktop is empty and I cannot launch any folder.</strike>

5. Then I reinstalled `nautilus` and the desktop (icons and folders) reappeared after logging out and on again.

Looks like this was it, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short summary of what I did correctly or wrong.

1. Check the [log files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) to understand what was happening:

   - `/var/log/apt/history.log`
   - `/var/log/dpkg.log`
   - syslog
2. Instead of uninstalling `mesa` packages it might have been more clever to install a bug free alternative (older or newer versions). That is obviously trial and error. Uninstalling `mesa` packages caused that important packages such as `gdm3` and `nautilus` and a lot more (334) have been removed, too.
3. File a bug for Mesa here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues
4. If needed reinstall the [`ubuntu-desktop` meta package](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages).