# Ubuntu 20.04.1 upgrade failure / ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: colord'

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, do-release-upgrade, mesa

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04.5 to 20.04.1 via:

```bsh
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This fails as follows:

> ...
>
> Could not calculate the upgrade
>
> An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
>
> This was likely caused by:
> Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu  Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge  package to remove software from a
> Launchpad PPA and  try the upgrade again.
>
> If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the
> command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If
> you want to investigate this yourself the log files in
> '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade.
> Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.

The tail of `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` contains the following error:

```
...
2020-10-11 18:36:30,320 WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)
2020-10-11 18:36:31,747 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'Broken packages after upgrade: colord'
2020-10-11 18:36:31,747 DEBUG abort called
2020-10-11 18:36:31,755 DEBUG openCache()
2020-10-11 18:36:37,070 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-117 with 
2020-10-11 18:36:37,071 DEBUG Comparing 4.15.0-118 with 4.15.0-117
2020-10-11 18:36:37,824 DEBUG /openCache(), new cache size 99980
```

Here are the reverse package dependencies of `colord`:

```bsh
$ apt-cache rdepends colord
colord
Reverse Depends:
  colord-sensor-argyll
  gnome-control-center
    colord:i386
  cups-filters
    colord:i386
  cups-daemon
    colord:i386
  cups
    colord:i386
  xiccd
    colord:i386
  krita
    colord:i386
  gnome-color-manager
    colord:i386
  foomatic-filters
    colord:i386
  dispcalgui
    colord:i386
  diffoscope
    colord:i386
  colord-sensor-argyll
    colord:i386
  colord-sensor-argyll
  colord-data
  colord-sensor-argyll
    colord:i386
  argyll
    colord:i386
  libcolord2
    colord:i386
  libcolord-gtk1
    colord:i386
  gnome-control-center
    colord:i386
  cups-filters
    colord:i386
  cups-daemon
    colord:i386
  cups
    colord:i386
  colord-data
```

I recently had [a segmentation fault issue with `mesa`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264564/ubuntu-18-04-4-startup-stuck-after-package-updates-mesa-segmentation-fault) and installed a version from `ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa`. This might cause the upgrade problem now.

The following would happen if I remove the `colord` package:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get remove colord 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apg colord-data gnome-control-center-faces gnome-online-accounts libcolorhug2 libnss-myhostname linux-headers-4.15.0-117 linux-headers-4.15.0-117-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-117-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-117-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-117-generic python3-macaroonbakery python3-nacl
  python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons python3-rfc3339 ubuntu-system-service
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  colord gnome-control-center ubuntu-desktop
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
After this operation, 5,782 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

This does not sound like a good idea because last time I removed `ubuntu-desktop` the UI did no longer start-up. See linked post.

## Question

How can I resolve the upgrade problem without risking the segmentation fault to reincarnate?

## Related

- [Ubuntu 18.04.4 startup stuck after package updates / mesa segmentation fault](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264564/ubuntu-18-04-4-startup-stuck-after-package-updates-mesa-segmentation-fault)
- [Can't seem to upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04 due to held back packages: libsensors4, libsensors-config, colord](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230374/cant-seem-to-upgrade-to-20-04-from-18-04-due-to-held-back-packages-libsensors4)
- [libsensors5 or libsensors-config upgrade problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144976/libsensors5-or-libsensors-config-upgrade-problem)
- [Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 failed ...](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2451652)

Comment: Have you tried removing the broken package?

Comment: No, I have not. I fear that it will remove it dependencies with it and the UI will no longer start up as it happened in the linked issue.

Comment: maybe this can help you
https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: you need to remove all ppa's and update all ubuntu packages to the latest version, then you can move on to change the release. Remove the ppa's, try to update apt without them. If you are lucky, the problem is gone.

Comment: I unckecked all PPAs and updated all packages to the latest version. Still the mentioned package blocks the upgrade. Please have a look at the linked issue to understand why I installed it.

Comment: How can dependent packages still function if I remove the one package which blocks the upgrade?

Comment: you can try to upgrade with debian way.  your mesa ppa offers packages for focal too. But first off all make a backup :D

Comment: @nobody Can you please describe the exact steps? The question is whether the focal mesa package is newer then the PPA mesa package I have currently installed aka. does not cause the segmentation fault.

Comment: that we do better in chat. For security there have to be some simulations. Maybe a mod ist so kind and open one

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall colord`? I'd also give `sudo aptitude -f install` a try. What does `sudo dpkg-reconfigure colord` tell you?

Comment: The proper way is to remove the ppa and the installed mesa, then do the upgrade from the command line, segfault or not, reinstall mesa, reboot. After that, you can test your new 20.04.1 where the issue should be gone. Cannot say exactly since running 20.10 already with Mesa 20.2.1 and OpenGL 3.0 here.

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`  please.  Need to know if other ppa's were bound in.

Comment: @nobody As requested the [output](https://pastebin.com/4RDhmcv9) of the `grep` command. I unchecked all external PPAs earlier.

Comment: @emk2203 Do you mean I should remove `colord` and `mesa-utils` and immediately run the upgrade without rebooting in between and then hoping that the new Ubuntu version when starting up no longer installs a buggy version of the package?

Comment: @starkus The output of `sudo dpkg-reconfigure colord` is `colord.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.`.

Comment: @nobody Sorry, I already started the upgrade by uninstalling `colord` and `mesa-utils` and its dependencies before. It is running right now. I will let you know how it turned out.

Comment: I am looking forward to you posting the result. Yes, this is what I meant - borne out of experience in other cases. When the package manager has issues, it's often catastrophic to reboot in between the fixes.

Comment: Upgrade done. As stated I removed `colord` and `mesa-utils`, started the upgrade. It went well. Then *System Settings* and desktop icons were missing which ended up that I completely removed `mesa` packages (from the PPA) via *Synaptic Package Manager* and then installed `gnome-control-center` cleanly which also installed `mesa` packages. Now the system seems fine. - Thanks everybody for the hints. I am not sure how to handle the bounty. I probably post my own answer (?)

Comment: Please do. You did the work for it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After all helpful hints, questions and comments I became inpatient with myself and decided to give the upgrade another try. Here is what I did:

1. `sudo apt-get remove colord`
2. `sudo apt-get remove mesa-utils` - This also removed `ubuntu-desktop`

This unblocked the `do-release-upgrade` command. No reboot at this step.

3. `sudo do-release-upgrade`

After ~2h of downloading the upgrade process requested a reboot. I confirmed. The upgrade went well - the system started.
After inspecting the new operating system I noticed that I could neither open the *Settings* nor change the background image nor could I install `ubuntu-desktop` or `gnome-control-center`. Also no files where shown on the *Desktop* although I could `ls` them in the folder.
After a while I figured that these packages where still blocked by some `mesa` packages originating from `ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa`.

4. I decided to completely remove all `mesa` package via *Synaptic Package Manager*
5. `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center` which transitively installed `mesa` packages
6. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
7. Reboot.

After restarting the system all files on the *Desktop* where shown, I was able to launch the *Settings* and change the background image. - Thank you everyone!

Comment: It's best to first roll back what the ppa did. For this, you need `ppa-purge`. Install it BEFORE you have problems with the package manager. It's 25 kB and I always have it installed. Then, you can run `sudo ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa`, you can do step 1, `ubuntu-desktop` should still be there. Then 3, reboot, done.

Comment: Although I had a different set of package issues that started with `evolution-data-server` instead of `mesa-utils`, this process solved the problem exactly as described.  I also had the stuck `ubuntu-desktop` in my log files, but it wasn't removed with the `apt-get remove`.

Answer (score 1):

For people who need it: `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing; sudo dpkg --configure -a; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo fuser -vki /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo dpkg --configure -a;`

Comment: I hereby confirm that I tried your commands but they did not help me so far. Nevertheless, I appreciate your post.

Comment: if you remove the broken package like mentioned in another above comment, it *shouldn't* ideally remove dependencies unless you run a purge command or run `sudo apt autoremove` after.. not sure about why it is seg faulting though :/