# Broken packages when upgrading to 20.04

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.04

I am trying to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 but I get the error message:

```
Could not calculate the upgrade

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.

This was likely caused by:
* Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu
Please use the tool 'ppa-purge' from the ppa-purge 
package to remove software from a Launchpad PPA and 
try the upgrade again.

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If you want to investigate this yourself the log files in '/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

I have looked at the [main.log](https://github.com/Kikkomann/laughing-sniffle/blob/master/main.log) and [apt.log](https://github.com/Kikkomann/laughing-sniffle/blob/master/apt.log), but my Ubuntu skills are not good enough to understand them and I am unsure if I can just delete all the broken packages.

Comment: same ppa; same problem. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281969/ubuntu-20-04-1-upgrade-failure-error-dist-upgrade-failed-broken-packages-aft?noredirect=1#comment2179837_1281969